# How to search for a value if exists or not in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have two things:

- category
- section

I need to check if a specific section exist in specific category or not:

example: [image: Result]

How to get status result if Exists or Not?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A4:A="";;IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A4:A&B4:B; 
 FLATTEN(G3:H3&G4:H); 1; 0))=""; "none"; "exists")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(A2:A),IF(COUNTIF(INDEX($F$2:$G,,MATCH(A2:A,$F$2:$G$2,0)),B2:B),"Exists","None"),))
```

[image]